# How to guard against invalid instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier in Swift

Tags: swift2, storyboard, ios9, guard-statement

In Swift, how do I guard against calling `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` on an identifier that's not valid?

Most solutions I have seen on SO uses try...catch in Objective-C, but the solution does not work in Swift because `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` does not throw.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a bug in the current API (iOS 9 as of today) for the Swift version. Either `storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` should return `UIViewController?` or it should be able to throw exception. The Objective-C version throws exception which can be dealt with try-catch clause.